# GQL files are not loading

Tags: babeljs, graphql, nodemon, apollo-server

I have .gql files where I have schema of my module. When I am making changes into it, it is not loading with new changes, however my schema server restarts.

I have this command `"start": "nodemon -e gql,js ./src/server.js --exec babel-node"` but it is not using latest changes made in gql file.

.babelrc

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-inline-import",
      {
        "extensions": [".json", ".gql", ".graphql"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I run schema server with `npm start`. Here are the details of graphql tools

```
"graphql": "^0.10.5",
"graphql-resolvers": "^0.2.0",
"graphql-tools": "^2.0.0-alpha.9",
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue ?

Comment: @N Sharma Have you solved it? We are also facing the same issue, any pointers would be helpful. nodemon is just ignoring the changes in *.gql files